# Java web Application memory usage on WebLogic Server

Tags: java, memory-management, weblogic, web

I have a web application deployed on a WebLogic server.

The server comes down very often. I need to figure out if my web application could be the cause. Is there some way I could monitor the memory usage of my application on the WebLogic server or is there a memory log that is generated on the WebLogic server. Please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by "Server comes down?" - does it mean the server shuts down? The server log files are a great way of knowing the possible cause for this. Did you analyze the log files? If not, please do so and update the question with your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to check your application memory footprint you can profile your application, I have used [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html?gclid=CI6ImuG6yawCFYUc6wod2WbiqQ).

Another way is to add log statements to calls which you think can be using a lot of memory like before method call

```
long freeMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
```

then once method is finished

```
logger.info("Total memory usage = " + (Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory() - freeMemory));
```

Another way is to turn on Weblogic diagnostic, you can read more [at](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13150_01/jrockit_jvm/jrockit/geninfo/diagnos/ctrlbreakhndlr.html)

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

It's not WebLogic-specific, but JVisualVM is very useful for figuring out where memory is going and comes comes with the JVM distribution (Java 6+, IIRC).  It lets you slice and dice memory in a bunch of ways, especially if you suspect the garbage collector.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using a product like AppDynamics:

http://www.appdynamics.com/weblogic-monitoring.php

They have a free lite version, and a free trial available for their pro version.  Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic server does already shows this kind of information for you. You can check memory dinamically accessing the dashboard. http://$ADMIN_SERVER_ADDRESS/console/dashboard  this works for weblogic 10.3.3 + if you are using an older version you can deploy the wldf diagnostic extension to the admin server to have access to the dashboard.

You may also monitor your server for other information selecting your server instance from the Administration console and than select the server you want to monitor and hit the monitoring tab, you will find lots of other information on your running server there.

Also if you are using JRockit as a JVM you should consider using JRockit Mission Control which gives you a full profile for weblogic server.

regards.